Movie about monster/parasite that enters from the mouth
I think this movie is from late 1970s/early 1990s or something - it's quite old.
I only remember this scene: A woman is sleeping, and then the parasite (which looks like long black intestines of sorts) creeps down from the ceiling. It goes in through this woman's mouth. After that, she wakes up and sees her stomach going black slowly.
I only know that this parasite enters from person to person through their mouth.  If I'm not wrong, the sleeping woman has blonde hair. The parasite is big and long, and its diameter is as big as a mouth. It's not about zombies. I'm not sure if there were multiple parasites.

A 40 year time span of mouth parasite movies? Ouch. Anything else you can think of to narrow it down? Was it black and white, or color? Aliens involved? Zombies? Multiple parasites? Anything?

I'm so sorry I guess I push the movie year way too far back, I'm pretty sure now it's at least from 1980 until early 1990s.
No, it's not zombies, just parasitic monster I guess.
Multiple parasites... I'm not sure :(

@wendy some other story element you know. How does character look etc etc

@cde I'm sorry it's not that one, this parasite is bigger and longer than that, kinda like black intestines at least the diameter is as big as mouth.

...or Shivers or Slither. Although both outside the (edited) range.

@AnkitSharma If I'm not wrong the sleeping woman has blonde hair, other than that I really really forgot :(

I think you're after the Alien rip-off Proteus from 1995.

Group of heroin smugglers finds shelter on abandoned oil rig after their ship had exploded. Soon they find that the oil rig was just cover for biological experiment. One of the results is Charlie - shape-shifting monster with ability to absorb the memory of its victims. However, even such creatures have their own bad habits.

There's a scene where woman is on a hospital bed and the parasite, which looks like black intestines, falls from the ceiling, creeps up and enters her mouth. The sheets on her stomach then darken. Here's the trailer:




You're right that's the one, Thanks! Sorry for troubling you guys so much lol, it's just the "I suddenly remembered this scene from this really old movie and I need to find out what that is" thing suddenly get me you know haha.

Possibly the movie Parasite (1982)
There is a very vivid scene (probably the most remembered in the film) where a parasite drips down from the ceiling.  It's most remembered because of the 3-D effect (the movie was released in 3-D in theaters), which was incredibly creepy.  I can vouch for that; I remember seeing this in a theater.
Here's the trailer:




It's called Night of the Creeps.



